# Dividir códigos em arquivos .py

Tags: python

Eu comecei agora a programar, e comecei no python, então comecei a pesquisar mais a fundo nessa linguagem, e fui ver uns vídeos de programação de jogos, nesses vídeos ví que o jogo era dividido em diversas partes (como UI, um sistema de chat in game, o jogo em si) e queria saber como é que se executa diversos arquivos .py como um só código!!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Utilizando o "import":

Você deve importar os módulos utilizando o `import`. Existem várias formas de importar um módulo, veja elas abaixo:

```
import module                              # Importa o módulo com todos os seus dados
import module as otherModuleName           # Importa o módulo e troca o nome dele
from module import *                       # Importa todos os dados do módulo
from module import data1, data2, data3     # Importa dados específicos do módulo
from module import data as otherDataName   # Importa dados específicos e troca o nome deles
```

O que o `import` faz é executar o módulo (*script .py*) e importar para dentro do seu programa os dados desse módulo (variáveis, funções e classes). Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

**registra.py**

```
url = "www.siteExemplo.com"

name = input("Digite seu nome: ")
password = input("Digite sua senha: ")
validateProfile(name,password)  # Função para verificar se os dados estão corretos.
```

**site.py**

```
import registra

print("Obrigado %s por se registrar em nosso site!"%registra.name)
print("Você pode fazer login clicando neste link: %s/login"%registra.url)
```

Perceba que neste exemplo, o código do arquivo **registra.py** é executado normalmente e os dados dele são passados para o código que está sendo executado.

Um outro detalhe importante que podemos notar é que nós utilizamos o ponto (.) para pedir pelo dado do módulo. Se não quiser sempre utilizar ponto para utilizar os dados, você pode importa-los do módulo utilizando o asterisco (importa todos os dados do módulo), ou então importando dados específicos. Exemplo:

```
from registra import *  # Importa todos os dados do módulo

print("Obrigado %s por se registrar em nosso site!"%name)
print("Você pode fazer login clicando neste link: %s/login"%url)
```

## Pacotes em Python:

Para manter um código bem organizado, talvez você queira dividir os seus módulos em pacotes. Exemplo:

```
Jogo
Jogo/Jogador/
Jogo/Carro/Itens
Jogo/Cenario/
```

Em Python, você pode importar módulos que estejam em outros diretórios através de pacotes. A ideia de importar é a mesma que você viu, só que antes do nome do módulo a ser importado, você deve passar o nome da pasta seguido de um ponto. Exemplo:

```
from Jogo.Jogador import Personagem
from Jogo.Carro.Itens import Roda, Volante
from Jogo.Cenario.Arvores import *
```

Para saber mais, leia a documentação [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).