# Função para importar arquivo .py?

Tags: python, funções, importação

Boa tarde, criei um arquivo chamado teste.py com código que busca informação de um banco de dados e transforma em um Dataframe. Estou com dificuldade em criar uma função e importar esse arquivo, segue o que tentei fazer:

```py
import teste.py
teste.ipynb.path.insert('teste.py', "C:\Users\pasta\Documents\WPy64-3760\notebooks")
```

Erro ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'teste.py'; 'teste' is not a package.

Answer (score 1):

Este erro está sendo gerado porque você está tentando importar o módulo `py` do pacote `teste`, ou pelo menos, é assim que o interpretador entende.

Na linguagem Python você não deve colocar a extensão do arquivo ao importar o módulo. Sendo assim, o seu código deveria estar dessa forma:

```
import teste
teste.ipynb.path.insert('teste.py', "C:\Users\pasta\Documents\WPy64-3760\notebooks")
```

Além disso, o ponto `.` é utilizado para informar ao Python que um módulo X está dentro de um certo pacote. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
# Árvore de diretórios:
#
# carro/
# carro/config/
# carro/config/motor.py
# carro/roda.py
# carro/volante.py
# piloto.py

import carro.config.motor # Importa o módulo "motor.py" do pacote "carro/config"
import carro.roda         # Importa o módulo "roda.py" do pacote carro
import carro.volante      # Importa o módulo "volante.py" do pacote carro
import piloto             # Importa o módulo "piloto.py" que está no diretório atual
```

Para saber mais sobre importação em Python veja [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427915/157404) outra resposta.